# Point a url in magento app to a different app

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a magneto application running on Apache. I want the home page of this application to point to a completely different app:

So for example, if

```
localhost:80/
```

was accessed, redirect it to

```
localhost:3000/
```

I want this since we are changing magento app to react app page by page and we have our react app running on `localhost:3000`, what would be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the most practical solution for you to use is a reverse proxy:

You need to enable `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`, then in the Magento vhost config:

```
ProxyPass "/sub-path-for-react/" "http://localhost:3000/sub-path-for-react/"
ProxyPassReverse "/sub-path-for-react/" "http://localhost:3000/sub-path-for-react/"
```

Of course here `sub-path-for-react` is an arbitrary path you have to set yourself.

For more complex rules you also have [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) that allows regexp usage.

Comment: Hey, could you please exactly specify the files and steps? I am completely new to Magento and apache thing so not familiar to any of this.

Comment: Sure, maybe you can tell me more about your setup in the question: distro, which URLs you want to go to the app, which URLs you want to go to Magento, etc.

Comment: I am on an ubuntu system. For now, I want only the home page i.e localhost:80 to be redirected to localhost:3000 so that homepage is served from React app and rest of the links from Magento website. However, I will be going page by page so eventually I would want localhost:80/catalog to be served from localhost:3000/catalog.

Comment: If you want to do that, you need to worry about static assets like javascript and images. Do you know what their address is? (in the React app)